# Current in RC circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors

I don't quite understand this.
Here's a simple RC circuit, consisting of only a resistor and a charged capacitor in series.[image: Simple RC circuit]

where the formulas at work are:

[image]

The way I see this, I<sub>r</sub> is "caused" by a potential difference across a resistor, while I<sub>c</sub> is due to the change in voltage in the capacitor. If these two cancel each other out, will the total current in the circuit be 0, then? I'm sorry if I seem to be missing out on some very basic concepts. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the same current. It is just denoted by different variables and polarity.

Comment: @EugeneSh. not necessarily, schematic is confusing.. is that node at the top a voltage entry point? If so Ic <> Ir

Comment: @Trevor Well, the description tells this is the complete circuit.

Comment: @Trevor if you're wondering, I "snipped" that schematics from "Fundamentals of Electric Circuits, 5th Edition" by Matthew O. Sadiku. And yes, let's assume it is a complete circuit.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yup I know :)

Answer (score 1):

When looking at current the direction of the arrow matters....

\$I_c = -I_R\$

That does NOT cancel out because the arrow for \$I_R\$ is in a different direction around the circuit from \$I_C\$.

All it is saying is the current going down through the capacitor is the same value as the current going up though the resistor.

Comment: A simple LC circuit can be called as tank circuit. Do we have any name for RC circuit as well?